# How big can I print this image?

Tags: printing, resolution, dpi

I have a JPG file with a resolution of 3000x2077. How big can I print this image ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on how big a printer you have, which of course we have no way of knowing.

Comment: It's a poster type of image and I want to print it pretty big to hang it on my wall, I am giving the image out for printing so I just want to know how big it can be

Comment: it can be as big as you want, it depends how many pixels per inch you want to print it at, and what sort of quality you're looking to achieve, and what media you're wanting to print on

Comment: Can I print on an A1 size sheet with good quality ?

Comment: _And_ the content of the image. Please see the existing question and its answers, which should cover all of these concerns.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a JPG file with a resolution of 3000x2077. How big can I print this image ?

**Just divide.** If you want to print the image at 300 dpi, the size will be `(3000px/300dpi x 2077px/300dpi) = 10in x 6.9in`. If you want to print it as a poster, you'll have to accept a lower resolution. Say you want it to be 30" in the longer dimension: `3000px/30in = 100dpi`, so you'd get an image that's 30in x 20.7in. That's not a gallery print or anything, but it'll probably look fine on your wall.